# After successful login user is not logged into YII2 frontend

Tags: authentication, yii2

If I run the login function it prints `User`.

```
public function actionLogin(){
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        echo "guest";
    } else {
        echo "User";
    }
    return $this->redirect(['dashboard']);
}
```

After redirect If I run the dashboard function it prints `guest`.

```
public function actionDashboard()
{        
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        echo "guest";
    } else {
        echo "User";
    }
}
```

My `Login` model:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is `getUser` function:

```
protected function getUser()    
{
    if ($this->_user === null) {
        $this->_user = Customer::findByEmail($this->email);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

Please help me to check in another function whether or not the user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully fixed this problem.

just change the backend/config/main.php or frontend/config/main.php

change this

```
'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\Customer', //or Any models you want
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
]
```

Comment: This is already in my frontend\config\main.php
    'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'frontend\modules\customer\models\Customer',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl'=>['login'],
        ],

Comment: Please any other answer?

Comment: can you please post the DB log using Yii debugger?